# Interpreting, Write failed: Broken pipe message for cli php script

Tags: php, command-line-interface, broken-pipe

I'm running a php script from ssh with the following command

```
./script.php &
```

The script is a has a loop in is supposed to loop about 800,000 times (so it takes a few days to run). However it is currently stopping a couple thousand loops into the process. My error handlers are not catching any error from the script but the console reads.

```
Write failed: Broken pipe
```

Can anyone shed any light on what this message means, what kind of problem this indicates, and how I might go about tracking it down?

Update:

To summarize what the script does it selects 800,000 row from a table in my data base (hosted on the same server as the script). For each row it makes a rest call to a third party site and then writes that data to a different table in the same database (hosted on the same server as the script).

Comment: Without code, it's just wild guessing.

Comment: Are you redirecting the script's output? Does the script write to a network connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Broken pipe` has two causes:

1. The program is writing to a pipe, either because it's using a function like `popen()` or the script's output is redirected to a pipeline, and the program reading from the pipe exits (or closes its end of the pipe for some other reason).
2. The program is writing to a network connection, and the connection is closed by the other end.

Comment: Hi Barmar, thanks for your response. I don' think scenario #1 applies to my script. My script does make a rest call to a third party web service (see update to question) is that writing to a network connection?

Comment: It doesn't usually happen in simple HTTP request/response connections. It's usually in long-lived connections where you're writing bulk data.

Comment: I'm making about 800,000 rest calls and writing each result to a database. Do you think that qualifies for scenario #2? Any advice on how to debug this?

Comment: I'd expect each call to be independent, but maybe there's a problem in the way the REST library uses persistent connections, and it doesn't handle failures properly. Maybe you should post your code.